# A Flowable with a flowable?

Tags: json, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am a newbie in RxJava2, and am hoping that someone can give me a sanity check for how I plan to implement a flowable...

Basically, we could have an array of 1 to 1000 Run.json entities, and
each Run.json entity has two components: projectInfo and runInfo. The
runInfo entity has an array of sample data being collected during the run.
The length of the array will be quite large... 50000 to 500000 objects.

```
[  
   {
      "projectInfo":{ 
         "name":"Abc Def"
      },
      "runInfo":{  
         "runId":"abc123",
         "samples":[  
            {
               "sensor1":12345.678
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

There are several services that will operate on these Run.json objects:

- Statistical analysis of the samples;
- Drawing the sample data on an aerial image;
- Report generation;

Each of these activities requires all of the data in the Run.json entity, such as the runId and project name.

MY PLAN:
I have created a Jackson based parser to synchronously transform a run.json file to a Kotlin entity, and have implemented Flowable.generate to provide a backpressure aware, async stream of Run json entities to subscribers.

SANITY CHECK:
My plan is probably overkill for a Flowable of run.json files that will consist of 1 to 200 files.  The real issue is to how to flow the samples.

So...

Should I stream each Kotlin Run object to each of the services  (i.e. split one stream into three streams), and the services will Flowably stream the samples?  This seems to make sense to me, but I would appreciate some feedback from more experienced people.

Thank you for your interest and time,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Streaming three different objects would be better also depend on use-cases. Other thing is use Scheduler io() and computation(), io() for reading files and computation() for processing elements as the input size is large.

Comment: Great suggestion about using the schedulers!  Thank you, Rohit!  At this point, the samples are Flowable, the projectInfo and runInfo are Singles.  The list of Run entities is a Flowable.  I need to do some experimenting to figure the best way to flow this data...